# Many Joins with single conditions VS Fewer Joins with multiple conditions

Tags: performance, t-sql, join, reporting-services, ssms

I found a query on the back end of a report that has multiple joins to multiple tables and thought that I'd improve the performance of the query by reducing the number of joins and consolidating the conditions on those joins. My theory being that every join would force the query to go over that table againso, fewer joins equal fewer reads.

What I found:

```
SELECT /* person fields, address fields, contact fields */

FROM PositionHistory ph
LEFT JOIN Person p ON p.ID = p.ID AND ph.Active = 'Y'

LEFT JOIN PersonAddress pa1 ON pa1.AddrID = p.ID AND pa1.Type = 'Current'
LEFT JOIN Address a1 ON a1.ID = pa1.AddrID
LEFT JOIN PersonPhone pp1_p ON pp1_p.ID = pa1.PhoneID AND pp1_p.Type = 'Phone'
LEFT JOIN Phone p1_p ON p1_p = pp1_p.ID
LEFT JOIN PersonPhone pp1_c ON pp1_c.ID = pa1.PhoneID AND pp1_c.Type = 'Cell'
LEFT JOIN Phone p1_c ON p1_c = pp1_c.ID

LEFT JOIN PersonAddress pa2 ON pa2.AddrID = p.ID AND pa2.Type = 'Work'
LEFT JOIN Address a2 ON a2.ID = pa2.AddrID
LEFT JOIN PersonPhone pp2_p ON pp2_p.ID = pa2.PhoneID AND pp2_p.Type = 'Phone'
LEFT JOIN Phone p2_p ON p2_p = pp2_p.ID
LEFT JOIN PersonPhone pp2_c ON pp2_c.ID = pa2.PhoneID AND pp2_c.Type = 'Cell'
LEFT JOIN Phone p2_c ON p2_c = pp2_c.ID

LEFT JOIN OtherContact oc1 ON oc1.PersonID = p.ID AND oc1.Type = 'Work'
LEFT JOIN OtherContact oc2 ON oc2.PersonID = p.ID AND oc2.Type = 'Home'
```

All this in an effort to get the data onto one row for presentation in an SSRS report.

I found that by using a matrix in the report I could get the data onto one row so that wasn't an issue anymore but the report was slow to run and I thought I'd work on the query to improve performance. What I tried:

```
SELECT /* person fields, address fields, contact fields */

FROM PositionHistory ph
LEFT JOIN Person p ON p.ID = p.ID AND ph.Active = 'Y'

LEFT JOIN PersonAddress pa ON pa.AddrID = p.ID AND pa.Type IN ('Current','Work')
LEFT JOIN Address a ON a.ID = pa.AddrID
LEFT JOIN PersonPhone pp ON pp.ID = pa.PhoneID AND pp.Type IN ('Phone', 'Cell')
LEFT JOIN Phone p ON p = pp.ID
LEFT JOIN OtherContact oc ON oc.PersonID = p.ID AND oc.Type IN ('Work', 'Home')
```

The number of rows returned increased by about 5 times, which makes sense. But when I used `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` I found that the number of overall logical reads increased from 22.7k to 37.3k which is the opposite of what I expected. At the very least I'd think it would be the same. Wouldn't the query be traversing the data fewer times with fewer joins? I need to understand what's going on here so that I can develop well-performing queries going forward but the original query isn't something I would've ever thought to do!

I might as well use the original query for the report at this point since it (apparently, somehow, bafflingly) performs better and then the report itself doesn't have to process the data onto one row. Any thoughts on how to improve would be welcome! I'm sure I'm missing something basic but I haven't found anything online or as I've tweaked the query.

Comment: First, read this:
https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

AFTER reading that:
Well, at least you raced your horses, which is good for you.
The problem with performance questions is that we can't really say why this or that would be better in your database without knowledge of existing indexes and also the query plan generated in each case. Use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to provide us a link so we can analyze.